Maximum area a traingle can have which can fit inside a circle of radius $r$?
So what is the maximum area of a triangle which can fit inside a circle of radius r?
My first approach: We know that $\text{ Circumradius }=\frac{abc}{4×\text [area-of- triangle}$ (here abc are side length of traingle).
I wrote abc in term of $2r sin a,2r sinb,2r sin c$.  Tried maximizing sina×sinb×sinc but wasn't able to do it
Approach 2: Using coordinate geometry I first made circle of radius r taking origin as center, I let vertex A of traingle at top of circle at y axis (rcos90 , rsin90). And other points with angle let x and y
Then I know that angle of arc at center is double than that of angle at circumference so I made equation in terms of x and y and angle of triangle. But after this I wasn't able to proceed further.
How do I proceed further?

This question is similar to: the triangle inscribed in a circle with maximum area. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. Found using a site search. Note there are other basic duplicates, e.g., use calculus to maximize the area of a triangle (which restricts the solution method ...

(cont.) to using calculus), and other quite similar problems, e.g., Maximum area of a triangle inscribed in a circle with radius r. (where this has the requirement that there's a constant difference of two of its angles).

Maximum area is obtained when each vertex is directly opposite the side connecting the other two vertices (because then the altitude from that side is at its maximum). What kind of inscribed triangle has each vertex directly opposite the side connecting the other two vertices?
